# composer.json script, returns 'event returned with error code 2', why?

Tags: php, composer-php

I was studying composer, and when creating this script, it returns 'event returned with error code 2'. While the script is executed properly, the parsing is correct and the result is the expected, I still get a delay and an error code regarding the script. What could be causing it and how should I fix it?

```
 //src

 <?php

    echo 'hello world';

 ?>
```

```
//composer.json
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "^3.6",
        "phan/phan": "^5.3"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "cs" : "phpcs --standard=PSR12 src/"
    },
```

```
//running

PS D:\xamp\htdocs\fonts\ambiente\buscador-cursos-alura> composer cs       
> phpcs --standard=PSR12 src/

FILE: ...:\xamp\htdocs\fonts\ambiente\buscador-cursos-alura\src\teste.php
----------------------------------------------------------------------
FOUND 3 ERRORS AFFECTING 2 LINES
----------------------------------------------------------------------
 1 | ERROR | [x] End of line character is invalid; expected "\n" but
   |       |     found "\r\n"
 5 | ERROR | [x] Expected 1 newline at end of file; 0 found
 5 | ERROR | [x] A closing tag is not permitted at the end of a PHP
   |       |     file
----------------------------------------------------------------------
PHPCBF CAN FIX THE 3 MARKED SNIFF VIOLATIONS AUTOMATICALLY
----------------------------------------------------------------------

Time: 102ms; Memory: 8MB

Script phpcs --standard=PSR12 src/ handling the cs event returned with error code 2
```

Comment: "it doesn't prevent execution" - what do you mean by that? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: You are running a script that checks your code, I imagine you are running it intentionally. You just need to read the the error messages if you want to address them. Unclear what's being asked here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

##### First Warning

`End of line character is invalid; expected "\n" but found "\r\n"`

Your line endings need to be LF and not CRLF, here's [an article](https://www.aleksandrhovhannisyan.com/blog/crlf-vs-lf-normalizing-line-endings-in-git/#:%7E:text=multi%2DOS%20codebase.-,LF%20%3A%20Line%20Feed,a%20new%20line%20of%20text.) which explains the difference. If you're using VSCode then you can change the line ending in the bottom right where it uses CRLF by default. If you're not using VSCode then you will need to Google how to change the line endings for your IDE.

##### Second Warning

`Expected 1 newline at end of file; 0 found`

PSR12 coding standards require an empty line at the end of your PHP files.

##### Third Warning

`A closing tag is not permitted at the end of a PHP file`

PSR12 coding standards state that closing PHP tags at the end of the file should be omitted.

```php
<?php
    echo 'hello world';
```

Comment: thanks, but this error "Script phpcs --standard=PSR12 src/ handling the cs event returned with error code 2" is related to this ? or something from composer ?

Comment: phpcs uses different exit codes depending on the result. Returns 0 when there are no errors. Returns 1 when there are errors or warnings and returns 2 when there are errors or warnings that are fixable by phpcs. See the commit here: https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/issues/930